# Check user account settings in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, settings, user-accounts

I am developing a facebook application for phototagging. I need to send e-mail notifications to users who has been tagged. For that I need to check the user account settings->notifications->photos->Tags you in a photo(check whether an e-mail should be sent or not). Is there any provision for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Your application will need to provide its own option. Also, users can separately block email/text notifications on a per-app basis from https://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?notifications

Comment: Yes I see that. Thanks for the reply. Kindly inform me if anything comes up in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

hello dude why do not use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and Query to [Photo_tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) Table to get the user_id who is being tagged and sent notification to him

Comment: Ya. But I want to check whether the user has allowed email notification on phototagging(in his account settings). Is there a method for that? Guess it's too complicated. Anyway I am going for the default notifications.

Comment: My dear you cannot access the account setting related information through your application or integrated facebook. If you want to get any information related to that then you have to depend upon the extended permissions provided by the facebook.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the question, Facebook already does this.

Account->Account Settings->Notifications

Comment: Yes. Facebook provides you with an option to receive mail notifications. But how do I(the programmer) know what he(user) has selected. Whether he has checked the box to receive mails on tagging or not? Base on his settings only I should send mail. Is it clear now?

Comment: Facebook automatically sends a mail notification. But I want to send a custom mail instead of the usual facebook mail notification.